# how to exclude program file Fine code coverage

Tags: c#, code-coverage, .net-6.0

[image: 1]

how to make Fine code coverage ignore the program file

I don't know how it work to exclude file

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your exclude entry.

If you want to exclude the `Program.cs` file you need to insert `**/Program.cs`.